# Can I offer strong guarantee to a function inserting 2 pairs in a std::map?

Tags: c++

I want to offer strong guarantee to a function that looks like this:

```
if(condition) {
    myMap.insert(key, val);
}
myMap.insert(anotherKey, anotherVal);
```

The standard says `insert` offers strong guarantee. My problem is I don't know how to handle the case where the second `insert` fails. `myMap` will be already modified, so it will only provide a basic guarantee.

Comment: You can copy and swap, but that's really inefficient if your map has more than a handful of elements.

Comment: Yes, I will probably need to make a tradeoff. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an exception occurs during the second insertion, catch it, delete the first element inserted, then rethrow.

```
// insert/emplace returns pair<iterator, bool>
auto insert_result = condition ? myMap.emplace(key, val)
                               : std::make_pair(myMap.end(), false);
try {
    myMap.emplace(anotherKey, anotherVal);
} catch (...) {
    if (insert_result.second) {
        myMap.erase(insert_result.first);
    }
    throw;
}
```

Note that this only works if `erase` doesn't throw. Luckily, the standard guarantees this under a rather mild assumption:

> For associative containers, no `clear()` function throws an exception. `erase(k)` does not throw an exception unless that exception is thrown by the container’s `Compare` object (if any).

([associative.reqmts.except]/1 in C++11)

So just make sure your comparison can never throw, and this should work.

Comment: You should be able to eliminate the requirement that the comparison doesn't throw by using the iterator returned by the first call to emplace, instead of using the key. You can also save yourself an additional lookup that way.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good point about efficiency. I don't know about your other claim though, I can't find any such guarantee in the standard, although I can certainly see why comparisons *shouldn't* be needed in that case.